# Typescript AWS Lambda + serverless debugging and tracing with VCode

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, webpack, lambda, serverless

I had created an AWS Lambda with a [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/intro/) and used their template to create a lambda:
`sls create --template aws-nodejs-typescript`

When I tried to run a default *'hello'* function in the local environment, it works just fine:

```
Serverless: Compiling with Typescript...
Serverless: Typescript compiled.
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": "{\"message\":\"Hello {\\\"headers\\\":{\\\"Content-Type\\\":\\\"application/json\\\"},\\\"body\\\":{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Frederic\\\"}}, welcome to the exciting Serverless world!\",\"event\":{\"headers\":{\"Content-Type\":\"application/json\"},\"body\":{\"name\":\"Frederic\"}}}"
}
✨  Done in 7.37s.
```

However, my initial goal is to figure out how to debug/trace this lambda in my local environment with the ability to place brakepoints. When I tried to run it *F5*, I am getting an error:

```
[offline] Loading handler... (/Users/mickey/vault/github/backend-work/merlin-lambdas/be-ts-sponsored/.build/.webpack/service/src/functions/hello/handler)
[offline] _____ HANDLER RESOLVED _____
offline: Failure: Cannot find module '/Users/mickey/vault/github/backend-work/merlin-lambdas/be-ts-sponsored/.build/.webpack/service/src/functions/hello/handler'
Require stack:
- /Users/mickey/vault/github/backend-work/merlin-lambdas/be-ts-sponsored/node_modules/serverless-offline/dist/lambda/handler-runner/in-process-runner/InProcessRunner.js
```

My question is how would I trace/debug this lambda, considering it is set with webpack.
Is there a way to debug/trace it or I must remove webpack in order to be able to debug?

Thank you for your help.

PS:
my vcode launch.json contains:

```
 {
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "DEBUG",
  "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "runtimeArgs": [
    "run-script",
    "debug"
  ],
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "restart": true,
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "port": 9229
}
```

and `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "serverless offline -s dev",
"build": "yarn tsc",
"tsc": "tsc --project tsconfig.json",
"debug": "export SLS_DEBUG=* && node --inspect ./node_modules/.bin/serverless offline -s dev",
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
```

},

Answer (score -1):

You can't trace put breaking points when you run your function with the serverless framework locally, you have few options instead:

Isolate your code from aws services that you can't be replicated locally (with jest mocks) like DynamoDB, SQS, SNS, S3...

Run your code like you do with any node application (I use jest most of the time) this way you can debug and put breakpoints independently from aws services.

- Use sst framework instead of serverless frameworks, it provides a solution to run lambda locally in its aws context (it is not official solution but a hack)

https://docs.serverless-stack.com/working-locally
https://docs.serverless-stack.com/debugging-with-vscode